# Managing user login segues in swift iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, view

I am trying to build an initial user login system for an iPhone app. I have created an API which holds all the user data. I have successfully made a HTTP connection from my swift code to my API, where I sent the users login details the API authenticates the user and sends the users data as JSON.

I have 2 views within my story board as seen below:

[image]

I want to control the segue transition, so it will only go to the next view only if the user is successfully authenticated and if not it stays on the same view but outputs a message on the same view as **"Wrong login details".**

Is there any way this could be achieved?

Apologies if I have made any mistake within my question. If you need more information to answer the question please let me know.

**UPDATE: Errors Encountered!**

After the making the suggested updates below I have the following errors. Any Idea how to fix them.

**My Code:**

[image]

**The Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to Initiate view Controller when user successfully logged it with below code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextViewController") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This way you can easily control your navigation and if user not entered correct information then you can show alert into else part as shown into below code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        if user successfully logIn {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextViewController") as! UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


        } else {

            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter correct Information", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Would you recommend I place the above code within the success part of my HTTP code. So once the user has been authorised and JSON data is being sent back then within the code I place the above if-else statement to change view? Again thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes you can use this code for change the view and dont forget to set identifier for you next view and remove segue.:)

Comment: Great! thank you so much. Is the "StoryBoardName" the storyboard ID of my login view ( where I enter the details ) and the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier is the storyboard ID of detail view where the successful login users details would be shown?

Comment: You can you your storyBoard name as "StoryBoardName" which is mostly "Main" as I updated into my answer and you `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier ` is storyboard ID of detail view.

Comment: Again thank you for the help. I have made the updates within my code but I am have some errors coming up. I have updated my questions with the errors. Could you please have a look, I'll be grateful.